# Reorder and repeat certain text columns

Tags: vba, excel

After doing a text to columns VBA, my data looks like this:

```
1995 (1)
(23:00)

Math 0630 
0830 Break 0930 
1000 English 1200 
1200 Lunch 1300 
1330 Free
```

Once I run the rest of the code, my data looks like this:

```
1995 (1) (23:00) 0630 Math 0830 0930 Math Break 1000 1200 Break English 1200 1300 English Lunch 1300 1330 Lunch Free
```

To make it easier to understand "0630 MATH 0830" is in one cell, and so on and so forth.

My issue is now I need the data to look like this:

```
1995 (1) (23:00) Math 0630 0830 Break 0930 1000 English 1200 1200 Lunch 1300 1330 Free
```

So basically the timings for the classes needs to be moved around if that makes sense. My code is below. Any type of help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Macro4() ' ' Macro4 Macro '

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("D29").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select


'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(1, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(37, 1), _
        Array(42, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(63, 1), Array(79, 1), Array(84, 1), Array(100, 1), Array( _
        105, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(129, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Rows("1:6").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

Dim lastRow&, g& Dim findStr$

findStr = "Planning of"

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For g = lastRow To 1 Step -1 ' change this to 2 if you have headers
    If Cells(g, 1).Value = findStr Then
        'Range(Rows(i), Rows(i - 4)).Select
        Range(Rows(g), Rows(g - 4)).EntireRow.Delete
    End If Next g

Dim arr() As Variant Dim p As Integer, i& Dim ws As Worksheet Dim tws As Worksheet Dim t As Integer Dim c As Long Dim u As Long



Set ws = ActiveSheet Set tws = Worksheets("Sheet2") i = 1 With ws Do Until i > 100000
    u = 0
    For c = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'If c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column And .Cells(i, c) <> "" Then
        ReDim arr(0) As Variant
        p = 0
        t = 0
            Do Until .Cells(i + p, c) = "" And t = 1
                If .Cells(i + p, c) = "" Then
                    t = 1

                Else
                    arr(UBound(arr)) = .Cells(i + p, c)
                    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
                End If
                p = p + 1
            Loop

        If p > u Then
            u = p

        End If
        If c = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
            If .Cells(i + p, c).End(xlDown).Row > 100000 And .Cells(i + p, 1).End(xlDown).Row < 100000 Then
                i = .Cells(i + u, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            Else
                i = .Cells(i + p, c).End(xlDown).Row
            End If

        End If
        tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr

    Next c
     Loop End With With tws
    .Rows(1).Delete
    For i = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Left(.Cells(i, 1), 4) <> Left(.Cells(i - 1, 1), 4) Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next i End With

' ' Macro6 Macro '

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1:M67").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select End Sub
```

Comment: Wow those are some nested loops... `Do Until .Cells(i + p, c) = "" And t = 1` do you ever increment `i`? Also, why the test for `t=1`?? The `if` statement below simply sets `t=1`??

Comment: @findwindow I'm don't get why I included all the repetition. I'm pretty new to VBA so this is all confusing to me

Comment: Uh ok. Your code is fairly complex so unless you stole that code, you may be new but not exactly clueless. The fact that your data is out of order suggests that one of the increments is faulty so I tried to pinpoint it but got lost in your nested loops. I would look into `i` since it's what's going into the array. I don't think it increments (or does so properly). Edit: Chris' answer below is far simpler though.

Comment: From what you have posted, it looks like you want all the results in one cell.  If you start with your table in the beginning of your post, and your table is in, for example, `A1:A8`, then all you need is something like `=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A1:A8)`.  If you are using a version earlier than 2016, equivalent VBA code is pretty simple.  If you don't want the results in a single cell, then edit your question to show exactly what you have for data input, and what you want for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you are looking for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReOrderAllDataInAllCells()

Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Worksheets(1).Range("C5:G5")
    rngCell.Value2 = ReorderDataInCells(rngCell.Value2)
Next rngCell

End Sub


Public Function ReorderDataInCells(strUnsorted As String) As String

Dim strTemp As String

strTemp = strUnsorted
strTemp = Replace(strTemp, Split(strUnsorted, " ")(0), "")
If IsNumeric(Split(strUnsorted, " ")(UBound(Split(strUnsorted, " ")))) Then
    strTemp = Replace(strTemp, Split(strUnsorted, " ")(UBound(Split(strUnsorted, " "))), "")
End If
strTemp = Trim(strTemp) & " " & Split(strUnsorted, " ")(0) & " "
If IsNumeric(Split(strUnsorted, " ")(UBound(Split(strUnsorted, " ")))) Then
    strTemp = strTemp & Split(strUnsorted, " ")(UBound(Split(strUnsorted, " ")))
End If
ReorderDataInCells = strTemp

End Function
```

Of course, `Worksheets(1).Range("C5:G5")` will have to be adjusted to the actual location of the cells to be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should do the trick:

```
Sub MoveIt()
    Dim LastRow as Long, RowCol as Long

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For RowCol = 1 to LastRow
        Cells(1, RowCol).Value = Cells(RowCol, 1).Value
        Cells(RowCol, 1).Value = ""
    Next RowCol
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, that moved the wrong column to a row. I'm looking to move the text inside the cells if that makes sense